# Obtaining multiple values for same row

Tags: php, mysql

I have table A containing

```
id | data
1     10
2     20
```

and table B containing

```
id | a_id | value
1     1       abc
2     1       def
3     2       ghi
```

column a_id of Table B references to column id of table A. I have to retrieve last 4 rows of data from table A along with its corresponding value from table B. When i tried to retrieve it using this query

```
SELECT * FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.id = tableB.id ORDER BY tableA.id DESC LIMIT 4
```

I got duplicate row of id 1 of from table A as

```
id | data | value
1     10     abc
1     10     def
2     20     ghi
```

Is there any way so that i can reduce this duplicate data So that i can get single row of id 1 along with its two value?

Comment: SELECT *, tableb.value -- why are you selecting stuff twice

Comment: yes you can do this but it will be a single string with a delimiter.  `GROUP_CONCAT(tableB.value SEPERATOR ',')    ... GROUP BY tableA.id` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: If you are hell-bent on using square brackets, you can wrap up `GROUP_CONCAT` with `REPLACE()`: `REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('[' , tableB.value , ']')), ',','') as val1`

Comment: @cmorrissey, you should add your comment as an answer. That will bring closure to the question and get you the deserved credit.

Comment: So, you have a one-to-many relationship between your tables; getting multiple rows is somewhat expected/correct/the right thing. Just post-process it in PHP, e.g. by grouping the results by `a_id` into a multi-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `GROUP_CONCAT`, see the documentation here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(tableB.value SEPERATOR ',')
    FROM tableA 
    INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.id = tableB.id
    GROUP BY tableA.id
    ORDER BY tableA.id DESC
    LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score 0):

please use this query:

```
    SELECT * FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.id = tableB.id ORDER BY tableA.id DESC LIMIT 4 Group By tableA.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Just post-process it in PHP, e.g.:

```
$data = [];
while ($row = $result->fetchAssoc()) {  // or whatever you do to fetch your data
    if (!isset($data[$row['id']])) {
        $row['value'] = [$row['value']];
        $data[$row['id']] = $row;
    } else {
        $data[$row['id']]['value'][] = $row['value']
    }
}
```

Gives you a nice result like:

```
[
    1 => [
        id => 1,
        data => 10,
        value => ['abc', 'def']
    ]
    ..
]
```